# Toast that only shows on debug variants

Tags: android, toast

I would like to create a simple helper class that shows toast messages for debug variants only.

Used like this:

```
TOAST.makeText(context, "Debug Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**TOAST.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mypp.BuildConfig;

/**
 * Toast that only shows for debug build variants.
 */
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class TOAST extends Toast {
    public TOAST(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    public static TOAST makeText(@NonNull Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
        return (TOAST) Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    }

    @NonNull
    public static TOAST makeText(@NonNull Context context, int resId, int duration) {
        return (TOAST) Toast.makeText(context, resId, duration);
    }

    @Override public void show() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            super.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Though the cast is failing in my implementation:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toast cannot be cast to com.mypp.helpers.TOAST
            at com.mypp.helpers.TOAST.makeText(TOAST.java:23)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot typecast instance of `Toast` (a base class) to a derived class `TOAST`, though other way round is possible.

May I suggest that you change your implementation to something like below:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mypp.BuildConfig;

/**
 * Toast that only shows for debug build variants.
 */
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class TOAST {

    private Toast toast;

    public TOAST(Toast toast) {
        this.toast = toast;
    }

    @NonNull
    public static TOAST makeText(@NonNull Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
        return new TOAST(Toast.makeText(context, text, duration));
    }

    @NonNull
    public static TOAST makeText(@NonNull Context context, int resId, int duration) {
        return new TOAST(Toast.makeText(context, resId, duration));
    }

    public void show() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be simplified if we make `TOAST extends Toast` ?

Comment: @RyanR There is no reason to extend toast. There is nothing in the Toast.class you need access too.

Comment: @RyanR  The example usage of `TOAST` that you wanted will remain same irrespective of whether you extend `Toast` or not.

Comment: Yea, was just thinking if we could use `super.show()` in `show()` but it doesn't simplify anything.

Comment: I've edited your answer to remove `context` since it is not needed. This simplifies it further.

Comment: @RyanR Thanks, that makes sense - Context was not needed

Answer (score 0):

Thinking 'composing over inheritance', I believe that we can found a simpler solution.

```
public class DebugToast {

    public static class Builder {

        private final Toast toast;

        public Builder(Context context, String message, int length) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, length);
        }

        public Builder(Context context, @StringRes int message, int length) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, length);
        }

        public void show() {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) toast.show();
        }
    }

    public static Builder makeText(Context context, String message, int length) {
        return new Builder(context, message, length);
    }

    public static Builder makeText(Context context, @StringRes int message, int length) {
        return new Builder(context, message, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm all for simpler implementations, but keeping the usage as close to `Toast.makeText(...).show()` is really desirable.

Comment: The usage will be `DebugToast.makeText(...).show()`. Or any other name you want for your class.